# How to convert this array to associated array?

Tags: php

```
<pre>
array(5) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(10) "name_print" ["value"]=> string(5) "22222" }   
[1]=>array(2) { ["name"]=> string(6) "hem_up" ["value"]=> string(0) "" } [2]=> array(2)   
{ ["name"]=>string(13) "hem_up_double" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [3]=> array(2)  
{ ["name"]=> string(11)   "hem_up_size" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [4]=> array(2)   
{ ["name"]=> string(11) "waist_catch"   ["value"]=> string(0) "" } }   
</pre>
```

I have gotten such an array after json_decode in PHP. but I want to get a associated array like this:

```
array("name_print"=>22222, "hem_up"=>555, ...}
```

Comment: That's not an associative array?

Comment: that's great! What have you tried so far?

Comment: thats just a nested array what do you expect? and whats the end result?

Comment: There is a bunch of assoc arrays.

Comment: Could you post it nicely formatted, like `var_dump()` does? It's hard to see the structure when it's wrapped like that.

Comment: @Barmar , var_export would be better, what do you think?

Comment: That would be even better, so we could test code with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$out = array();
foreach ($in as $i) {
  $out[$i['name']] = $i['value'];
}
```

Comment: What values? All key names is unique.